# Some strange behavior in Js Number.parseInt function, can someone explain it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, lambda

I found some strange behavior in the javascript parse int function.

Check the following code:

```js
console.log([..."111"].map(Number.parseInt))
console.log([..."111"].map(x => Number.parseInt(x)))
```

When you run the first line, you get: [1, Nan, 1]

When you run the second line, you get: [1, 1, 1]

Can someone explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parseInt()` function is defined with **two** parameters: the string to parse, and a number indicating the numeric base to assume for the string representation. On the second iteration, the `.map()` call is effectively calling

```
Number.parseInt("1", 1)
```

and base 1 does not make sense. (Base 0 does not make sense either, but it ignores that.)

Recall that the `.map()` function passes 3 parameters to its callback function: an element from the array, an index, and the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

[`Number.parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) accepts 2 arguments if the second argument (called `radix` in MDN docs) is smaller than 2 or greater than 36, `NaN` is returned.